# Find the records matching a string in tableau

Tags: string, match, tableau-desktop, string-function

I need to find the records that matches a string. I am using 'contains' function but it's not fetching me any results.

Any idea on how can I get the records matching a string.

If contains([Description],"string with spaces and multiple sentence") then 'yes' else 'no' end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a similar way, the trick is how you draft the text inside the double quotes

This Worked!!!
[image: mine works perfectly]

Comment: Thanks but I need to match a string with multiple sentences. For eg:

Comment: Thanks . But I need a exact match for a sentence. For eg: "Hi , I am a Tableau learner: confirmed.

Comment: can you add a screenshot just like i did (edit in your question) for better understanding

Comment: Thanks MKD for your time. I actually was able to get the correct logic. There were spaces present in the paragraph due to (enter). I removed them using a single blank and now it works fine.

Comment: please mark my answer as correct, i tried to emphasize this clearly